# stacked area chart with secondary data range

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

What I have is this:

[image]

and I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

Using Calc 5, how do I manage the second column to be recognized as secondary data range?

Comment: probably you need to use pivotchart (at least this is the name in Excel, I don't know how it's called in Calc)

Answer (score 1):

As Máté Juhász suggested, a pivot table is the key. With the help of cloph in #libreoffice on Freenode I managed to get what I want. Here is the solution:

1. Insert header label for easier management of pivot table, easier to work with human readable labels than with generic Colum X, in this case date, category and data.
2. highlight the datatable and use Insert|Pivot Table (or Data|Pivot Table → create, depending of the version of LO
3. In the pivot table dialog drag the date to the rows area, the category to the column area, and value to the data portion, in the extended options you can uncheck the totals
4. highlight the data in the newly created pivot table and create another chart from it
5. be happy :-)

Result of the above sample:

[image]

Comment: I was going to suggest manually copying and pasting to separate the series.  Your method of using a pivot table makes the process much easier.

Comment: Would you mind modifying step 1 to make it clear that the labels are "date", "category" and "value".